# search text in data grid view and display all matching records C#

Tags: c#, .net

Attach picture of [image]code is working for me but only showing one row while data has multiple rows having same text.

Comment: Remove "break".and please next time post code as text

Comment: Probably more normal to bind your DGV to a datatable, and then just set `theDataTable.DefaultView.Filter = $"[CustReelId] = '{searchValue}'";`

Comment: You need to learn [how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "continue" instead of "break"